# create a database table in my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-framework-version

can i develop a application and create a database table in the application?
i am using visual studio window form application c# (.net framework), and database is using access .mdb file.

i am trying to create a database table in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set it up like this:

```
    public class CreateTableInMySQL
{
    private string connectionString = "ConnectionString"; //connection string goes here

    public void CreateTable()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YourTableName (
            Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
            ColumnName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            AnotherColumnName INT NOT NULL);"; 
            //You can wire up the Column and table names to the UI input
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Have the user input a table name and column names, types etc. and then wire them up to this method. Additionally, maybe add some user verification beforehand.
I would advise to NEVER let users create tables and do stuff with the SQL tables directly. Only allow this for admins of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can of course, but you will need to do it by your self.
You need to create in your application for exemple a button to create a collection. And the create it with your code.

Comment: How do i create datatypes in my application

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).